# Backbone server collection reorder

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fetch

I have problem with backbone. So I try reorder collection on server side and show it with backbone.

the code look like that

```
that.collection.fetch(
          data:
            page: my.selected + 1
            order: that.filter.order
          success: (data)->
            #do nothing
```

If server returns models I have/draw yet, nothing happend. But with new one all right.
Please, help me understand that.

Comment: I don't even think that's valid javascript ?

Comment: It's CoffeeScript code snippet :(